# Problems with Chinese in python

Tags: python, unicode

I have a Chinese program in python 2.7 that is giving me some problems

Code:

```
# -*- coding: gb2312 -*- 
import sys
command = raw_input(">>> ").decode(sys.stdin.encoding)
if (command == u"你好".encode('utf-8')):
    print "etc"
```

I get the error:

test_chinese.py:6: UnicodeWarning: Unicode equal comparison failed to convert both arguments to Unicode - interpreting them as being unequal
  if (command == u"����".encode('utf-8')):

Is there anything incorrect?

Comment: try this code `if (command == u"你好"):` instead of `if (command == u"你好".encode('utf-8')):`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to `encode` your unicode literal: `u"你好"`, so just use:

```
import sys
command = raw_input(">>> ").decode(sys.stdin.encoding)
if command == u"你好":
    print "etc"
```

Honestly, you should just use Python 3. Support for unicode is much better. Indeed, `str` are now sequences of unicode points, unlike "byte strings" in Python 2, which have been changed to the `bytes` data type. In Python 3, all you would need to do is:

```
command = input(">>> ")
if command == "你好":
    print("etc")
```

Comment: maybe you should gave valid ONE reason why you are encouraging the OP to use python2 in this case

Comment: @repzero sorry, what? I'm encouraging them to use *Python 3*, mostly for it's more streamlined unicode support.

Comment: Well put that in your response! don't go making a suggestion without backing it up!